# How to group SQL Value if the column is same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Needed help with SQL, tried for a while and still cant figure it out

MY Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(
    Sender              VARCHAR(255),
    Receiver            VARCHAR(255),
    MSG                 VARCHAR(255),
);
```

After Insert VALUES

```
SEND1   REC1    Hey whats up
SEND1   REC2    Yoo how are you
SEND1   REC1    Nothing much
```

What I've been trying to do is to

```
Select * FROM DATA WHERE Sender = 'SEND1'
```

However, I just wanted to show the second row and third row, basically if the SENDER and RECEIVER is same as previous row, ignore the previous row and took the last row only and no duplication of the same same SENDER and RECEIVER

Thanks

I am using SQL-SERVER

What I meant is to always take the last row of the same 'Sender' and 'Receiver', the first row and third row has same sender and receiver, so when I select statement, I just want the last one

Comment: What determines here `last row`? Also do you use mysql or sql-server ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze Hi, I am using SQL-Server

Comment: @CarmenC - How to find the order ? out of first record and last record which one to pick ? Do you have any other column to find the order..

Comment: @Prdp last record only. No other column, should I add date?

Comment: @CarmenC - Of course you need a identity column or date column to find the order of records ?

Comment: Ok lets say I added identity int named "Num", how to do the select statements?

Comment: @CarmenC - check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were suggested in the comments you can add an integer autoincrementing column **Num** in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(
Num integer IDENTITY(1,1),
Sender              VARCHAR(255),
Receiver            VARCHAR(255),
MSG                 VARCHAR(255),
);
```

Hence, the latest message has the highest number. Then you add values:

```
insert into Data values ('SEND1','REC1','Hey whats up')

insert into Data values ('SEND1','REC2','Yoo how are you')

insert into Data values ('SEND1','REC1','Nothing much')
```

Finally, you should try to run this query:

```
select * from Data
where Num in (
  select max(Num) from Data 
      group by Sender, Receiver)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per comments in question, considering you have an identity column to find the order of records. Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to find the latest `Sender/Receiver` message.

```
Select * from
(
Select Row_Number()Over(Partition by Sender,Receiver order by Num desc) Rn,*
From yourtable
) A
Where Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the OFFSET clause, to offset (skip) the first message.

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Sender = 'SEND1' OFFSET 1;
```

The trouble is you need will an id column or a datetimestamp to ORDER BY so you can guarantee the first message sent is not included.

e.g.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM Data
WHERE Sender = 'SEND1' 
ORDER BY id -- or a datetime column
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1;
```

I don't quite understand:

> basically if the SENDER and RECEIVER is same as previous row, ignore the previous row and took the last row only and no duplication of the same same SENDER and RECEIVER

But this should cover the case:

> I just wanted to show the second row and third row

Comment: What I meant is to always take the last row of the same 'Sender' and 'Receiver', the first row and third row has same sender and receiver, so when I select statement, I just want the last one

Comment: @CarmenC Looks like you have to include a LIMIT before the OFFSET, if you know your Data table isn't going to be bigger than 1000 you can amend the last line to read: LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1; I'll edit the code above for a general case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now got error Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have unique/PK `id` column and higher value means latest record. Then you can use:

```
select DATA.* from DATA 
join(
    select max(id) as maxid 
    from DATA 
    group by Sender, Receiver 
)t
on DATA.id = t.maxid
```

Comment: You can't assume.As there is no ID column in TABLE create statement.
You can suggest him that add one numeric column with primary key and then execute this query.

Comment: @SagarGangwal - I think you can understand context of that proposal in my answer, you don't?

Comment: I am..
But i just want to inform you that you can suggest him,instead of assuming something.